# Exception AssertionError: AssertionError() in 'pyobjus.protocol_forwardInvocation' ignored

Tags: python, kivy

I'm building a Kivy app that uses pyobjus to connect to a [TI SensorTag](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag2015/?INTC=SensorTag&HQS=sensortag). I've successfully gotten the app to find the sensor during a scan, but I can't get it to connect. I found some code [here](https://github.com/TangibleDisplay/twiz/blob/master/osx_ble.py), but it's for a different sensor. The error I'm getting is: `Exception AssertionError: AssertionError() in 'pyobjus.protocol_forwardInvocation' ignored` from pyobjus, but I can't figure out how to trace the error since it's being ignored.

1. How can I find what's causing the error (e.g. prevent pyobjus from ignoring the error)?
2. Better yet, does anyone have a simple working example of how to connect a device over BLE to Mac OSX?

**EDIT**

Here is the code, seems the issue is with the connect() function

```
class Ble(object):
    def check_le(self, central):
        state = central.state
        if state == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown:
            print 'CentralManager: Unknown state'
        elif state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn:
            print 'CentralManager: Ready to go!'
            return True
        elif state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff:
            print 'CentralManager: Bluetooth is powered off'
        elif state == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized:
            print 'CentralManager: The application is not authorized to use BLE'  # noqa
        elif state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported:
            print 'CentralManager: This hardware doesnt support BLE'

    def connect(self, peripheral):
        print "connecting"
        self.stop_scan()
        self.central.cancelPeripheralConnection_(peripheral)
        self.central.connectPeripheral_options_(peripheral, None, None)

    def disconnecte(self, peripheral):
        # XXX !
        print "Disconnect Not Implemented!"

    def create(self):
        self.callback = None
        self.peripherals = {}
        load_framework(INCLUDE.IOBluetooth)
        CBCentralManager = autoclass('CBCentralManager')
        self.central = CBCentralManager.alloc().initWithDelegate_queue_(
            self, None)

    def start_scan(self):
        print 'Scanning started on Mac OSX MJR'
        self.asked_services = []
        self.central.scanForPeripheralsWithServices_options_(None, None)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.pop_queue, 0.04)

    def stop_scan(self):
        print "stopping scan"
        self.central.stopScan()

    def pop_queue(self, dt):
        if self.queue:
            self.callback(*self.queue.pop(0))

    @protocol('CBCentralManagerDelegate')
    def centralManagerDidUpdateState_(self, central):
        print 'central state', central.state
        self.check_le(central)
        self.start_scan()

    @protocol('CBCentralManagerDelegate')
    def centralManager_didDiscoverPeripheral_advertisementData_RSSI_(
            self, central, peripheral, data, rssi):
        # print('centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:')
        # uuid = peripheral.identifier.UUIDString().cString()
        # if peripheral.name:
        #     print('-> name=', peripheral.name.cString())
        #     print 'uuid:', uuid

        keys = data.allKeys()
        count = keys.count()
        if count < 2:
            return
        name = peripheral.name.cString()
        # name = data.objectForKey_(keys.objectAtIndex_(count - 2)).cString()
        values = data.objectForKey_(keys.objectAtIndex_(count - 1))

        sensor = c.get_from_ptr(values.bytes().arg_ref, 'c', values.length())
        uuid = peripheral.description().cString()
        if self.callback:
            self.callback(rssi.intValue(), name, sensor)
        else:
            print uuid, name, sensor, rssi
        if uuid not in self.peripherals:
            pass
            #self.connect(peripheral)
        self.peripherals[name] = (peripheral, rssi)


    @protocol('CBCentralManagerDelegate')
    def centralManager_didConnectPeripheral_(self, central, peripheral):
        if not peripheral.name.UTF8String():
            return
        peripheral.delegate = self
        CBUUID = autoclass('CBUUID')
        service = CBUUID.UUIDWithString_('1901')
        peripheral.discoverServices_([service])

    @protocol('CBPeripheralDelegate')
    def peripheral_didDiscoverServices_(self, peripheral, error):
        for i in range(peripheral.services.count()):
            service = peripheral.services.objectAtIndex_(i)
            if service.UUID.UUIDString.cString() == '1901':
                break
        else:
            assert(0)
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics_forService_([], service)

    @protocol('CBPeripheralDelegate')
    def peripheral_didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService_error_(self, peripheral, service, error):
        print "discovered characteristic: ", service, service.characteristics
        for i in range(service.characteristics.count()):
            ch = service.characteristics.objectAtIndex_(i)
            if ch.UUID.UUIDString.cString() == '2B01':
                peripheral.setNotifyValue_forCharacteristic_(True, ch)
                print "set notify for chr {}".format(i)

    @protocol('CBPeripheralDelegate')
    def peripheral_didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic_error_(
            self, peripheral, characteristic, error):
        # probably needs to decode like for advertising
        # sensor = c.get_from_ptr(values.bytes().arg_ref, 'c', values.length())
        print "characteristic: {} notifying: {}".format(characteristic.UUID.UUIDString.cString(), characteristic.isNotifying)
        pass

    @protocol('CBPeripheralDelegate')
    def peripheral_didUpdateValueForCharacteristic_error_(self, peripheral, characteristic, error):
        # probably needs to decode like for advertising
        # sensor = c.get_from_ptr(values.bytes().arg_ref, 'c', values.length())
        data =  c.get_from_ptr(characteristic.value.bytes().arg_ref, 'c', characteristic.value.length())
        name = peripheral.name.cString()
        peripheral.readRSSI()
        rssi = peripheral.RSSI and peripheral.RSSI.intValue() or 0
        if self.callback:
            if self.queue is not None:
                self.queue.append((rssi, name, data))

            else:
                self.callback(rssi, name, data)
        else:
            print name, rsii, data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means there is an error somewhere in one of your protocol methods, like `centralManager_didDiscoverPeripheral_advertisementData_RSSI_()`. But you didn't provide any code.

I've updated my plyer BLE code now as well - it supports connecting and basic reading/writing of characteristics. It's a work in progress, and the code is pretty messy as it's been my BLE testing and learning environment. You can take a look at it here: https://github.com/kivy/plyer/pull/185

If you try to write your own code for this, a few things to keep in mind. First, make sure to keep a reference to the `CBPeripheral` object when connecting - otherwise the object will be deallocated and your connection will silently fail. Second, make sure to set the `CBPeripheralDelegate` via `peripheral.setDelegate_(self)` and not `peripheral.delegate = self` - the latter will not work and your protocol methods will not be called. Finally, there is a bug in pyobjus with passing bytes to a `void*` argument - this will prevent you from creating a binary `NSData` object to read/write characteristic values. I have a PR for that bug though (https://github.com/kivy/pyobjus/pull/26).

Comment: I added the code above. I am also seeing an error `Exception AttributeError: __NSCFNumber object has no attribute bytes in pyobjus.protocol_forwardInvocation ignored`   that appears is related to your PR #26

Comment: That's actually not related, my pyobjus PR #26 has to do with passing bytes to ObjC void* arguments. In this case, you're probably not actually getting what you expect from `data.objectForKey_(keys.objectAtIndex_(count - 1))` - try doing `data.objectForKey_(CBAdvertisementDataKeys.ManufacturerData)` instead, like in my plyer PR. This class is defined in `pyobjus.consts.corebluetooth` in the latest versions of pyjnius, but the actual value is `'kCBAdvDataManufacturerData'`.

Comment: Though TBH I'd like it if you would try my plyer facade and see if it works for you, since it will eventually be merged for everyone to use anyway. :)